# JQuery validation: Add method for checking duplicate values in a text-box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Below validation method will check for duplicate values in all textBoxes having class name checkForDuplicate

```
    $.validator.addMethod("checkForDuplicate", function(value, element) {
       var textValues = [];
        $("input.validateLocation").each(function() {
           if($(this).val() !== ""){
               var doesExisit = ($.inArray($(this).val(), textValues) === -1) ? false : true;
               if (doesExisit === false) {
                   console.log("adding the values to array");
                   textValues.push($(this).val());
                   console.log(textValues);
               } else {
                   console.log(textValues);
                   return false;
               }
           }

        });
        return true;
    });
```

but it is not working as intended, It is failing at first textBox only. help me to resolve this.

Comment: The problem is you are always returning true, never returning false

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are always returning true from your validate method, so try

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkForDuplicate", function (value, element) {
    var textValues = [],
        //initially mark as valid state
        valid = true;
    $("input.validateLocation").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            var doesExisit = ($.inArray($(this).val(), textValues) === -1) ? false : true;
            if (doesExisit === false) {
                console.log("adding the values to array");
                textValues.push($(this).val());
                console.log(textValues);
            } else {
                console.log(textValues);
                //update the state as invalid
                valid = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
    //return the valid state
    return valid;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jemu6/)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkForDuplicate", function(value, element) {
       var textValues = [];
        $("input.validateLocation").each(function() {
           if($(this).val() !== ""){
               var doesExisit = ($.inArray($(this).val(), textValues) === -1) ? false : true;
               if (doesExisit === false) {
                   console.log("adding the values to array");
                   textValues.push($(this).val());
                   console.log(textValues);
               } else {
                   console.log(textValues);
                   return false;
               }
           }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Bit late but try this one, this should solve your problem without adding an array.

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkForDuplicate", function (value, element) {

            //initially mark as valid state
            valid = true;
        $("input.validateLocation").each(function () {
            value1 = $(this).val();
            if ($(this).val() !== "") {
                $('input.validateLocation').not(this).each(function(){
                    if($(this).val()==value1){
                    valid=false;
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });
        //return the valid state
        return valid;
    };
```