# Alert and not allow if same word written twice in an input jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my input:

```
<input type='text' class='myprofiletags' name='my_profile_tags' value='' />
```

I want to alert and forbid the user if he/she writes the same word twice. I am entering values with commma e.g

```
games, animes, movies

jQuery('.myprofiletags').keypress(function(e)
    {
       if (jQuery(this).val().match(/,/g).length >= 10)
       {
            if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                e.preventDefault();  // stops the keypress occuring
                alert('No more profile tags are allowed');                                      
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: Please also share whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: do you mean hyderabad?

Comment: no no i am not from there :)

Comment: Here is the link for solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801985/jquery-validation-add-method-for-checking-duplicate-values-in-a-text-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set an event handler (onkeyup) on input box so that whenever user hits a key the handler gets called
- In event handler take the values of input box and split them on comma
- Check if any value is duplicate
- If no return true
- If yes show an alert

Synopsis:

```
$(".myprofiletags").keydown (function (e) {
    alert ($(this).val());
});
```

You can also use [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('input[name^="text"]').change(function() {
```

---

**Edit:** You are going in right direction, just split the value on comma and use each splitted value as an item of array.

See how to do that:

- [Split comma-separated input box values into array in jquery, and loop through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757671/split-comma-separated-input-box-values-into-array-in-jquery-and-loop-through-it)
- [Convert comma separated string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)

Comment: how do i check the value? can you please tell me